# How to view the current settings of Autovacuum in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, vacuum

I've found a million examples of how to set Autovacuum's configuration settings, but can't seem to find how to list the current configuration.

Postgres 9.1 is the version I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For the general settings use:

```
select *
from pg_settings 
where name like '%autovacuum%'
```

for table specific settings, check out the column `reloptions` in pg_class:

```
select relname, reloptions
from pg_class
```

You will probably want to join that to pg_namespace to limit this to a specific schema. Where joining needs to happen on the hidden col `pg_namespace.oid` (added 9.3+).

```
select relname, reloptions, pg_namespace.nspname
from pg_class
join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
where relname like 'data%' and pg_namespace.nspname = 'public';
```

Comment: Alternative query: `select * from pg_settings where category like 'Autovacuum'`

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html

Comment: The `like 'autovacuum%'` is wrong it should be `like '%autovacuum%'`, not all autovacuum settings start with the word `autovacuum`.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to see the vacuum settings for a specific table:

```
SELECT relname, reloptions FROM pg_class WHERE relname='tablename';
```

The general vacuum settings can be seen in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: I just tried this but it showed the field as null? the field is autovaccuuming

Comment: @Luffydude The field is autovacuuming?? Can you be more clear? In any case I guess that if reloptions is null it means that you are using the default vacuum settings (defined in postgresql.conf) for that table.